# Upload images in WordPress to match an ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some IDs in an array in the backend of a custom plugin.

```
$ids= array(548712, 872215, 645870, 217547, 654684);
```

How do I make it possible in WordPress to upload an image for each ID?
The images should be saved under `/wp-content/uploads/xyz` as `{ID}.png`.

I have already read a lot about file uploads in PHP, but I would be surprised if WordPress does not offer something much simpler.